# Users without the "Strunk & White" badge are redirected to the question page for edits done in the review page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

If users without the "Strunk & White" badge edits a question in the review page, they will find themselves in the question page, once the edit has been done. This is true for retagging a question, and for editing its content.

I could verify this in a site where my reputation is lower than 3k, and where I can retag questions.

Comment: I can verify this too.

Comment: if you wish to discuss opening up inline edit to lower rep users, open a separate request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by-design, if you do not have **full** edit rights you do not get the privilege to use the "inline edit" feature.

The edit page displays editing hints and a warning that the edit is going through the suggested edit queue.